# CSS stretch horizontal menu to fill all width

Tags: html, css, nav

[Here](http://exerion.comule.com/Default.html) is the link to my site. When you have a wide resolution there is no issue with the dispaly, but if with the brower I try to simulate a little resolution, I come across an issue :
The nav bar won't fill the entire page but only the width of the browser, even though I used width : 100%;

Here the code in CSS

```
header {
width: 100%;
/*min-width: 1000px;*/
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, .5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, .5);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, .5);
padding-top: 60px; /* Gere l'espace entre le top et la barre de menu */
background: url('../img/binding_dark.png');
}

nav {
margin-bottom: 30px;
width: 100%;

background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #353535 0%, #222222 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#353535), color-stop(100%,#222222));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #353535 0%,#222222 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #353535 0%,#222222 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #353535 0%,#222222 100%);
background: linear-gradient(top, #353535 0%,#222222 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#353535', endColorstr='#222222',GradientType=0 );
border-width: 1px 0 1px 0;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #000;
}
```

The header is the wide black block and the nav is inside it.

Here is an exemple of the issue:

[image]

The header won't fill all the page (horizontally), the li element would overflow, and gradient background would split.

Is there a solution to this please ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your corrected css and **[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/XXnFM/)**

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, .5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, .5);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, .5);
    padding-top: 60px; /* Gere l'espace entre le top et la barre de menu */
    background: url('../img/binding_dark.png');
}

hgroup,
main,
nav {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #353535 0%, #222222 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#353535), color-stop(100%,#222222));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #353535 0%,#222222 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #353535 0%,#222222 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #353535 0%,#222222 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #353535 0%,#222222 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#353535', endColorstr='#222222',GradientType=0 );

    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}

   /* nav:before {
        border-top: 1px solid #444;
    }

    nav:after {
        border-top: 1px solid #333;
    }*/

    nav ul {
        /*width: 808px;*/
        height: 45px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        /*border-left: 1px solid #111;
        border-right: 1px solid #444;*/
    }

    nav li {
        float: left;
        list-style-type:none;
    }
        nav li a {
            display: inline-block;
            /*width: 200px;*/
            width:auto;
            padding:0 50px;
            height: 45px;
            font: bold 15px 'Arial', sans-serif;
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 48px;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #111;
            filter: dropshadow(color=#111, offx=1, offy=1);
            border-left: 1px solid #444;
            border-right: 1px solid #111;

            background-color:#2B2B2B;
        }


            nav li a:hover {
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444 0%, #222 100%);
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#444), color-stop(100%,#222));
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444 0%,#222 100%);
                background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #444 0%,#222 100%);
                background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #444 0%,#222 100%);
                background: linear-gradient(top, #444 0%,#222 100%);
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#444', endColorstr='#222',GradientType=0 );
                /*background-color:#2F2F2F;*/
            }

            nav li a:active {
                background: #222;
                -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
                -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
                box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
            }

                nav li a:active:after {
                    content: "";
                    display: block;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 4px;
                    position: relative;
                    bottom: 6px;
                    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff5e1f 0%, #ff3410 100%);
                    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff5e1f), color-stop(100%,#ff3410));
                    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff5e1f 0%,#ff3410 100%);
                    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff5e1f 0%,#ff3410 100%);
                    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff5e1f 0%,#ff3410 100%);
                    background: linear-gradient(top, #ff5e1f 0%,#ff3410 100%);
                    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff5e1f', endColorstr='#ff3410',GradientType=0 );
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the li element stay in a black box, but the header still wont take all the page, but only the window width.

Answer (score 0):

There are other issues with the layout, but for the immediate problem, you could try

```
#page-wrap header {min-width: 1400px;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the li element now stay in the bar, but the page will extend too much.

Comment: Could you tell me more about the other issues please ?

Comment: How do you want the page to display on small screens? It would be better to change styles on small screens so that the content is not so wide.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the width of the `nav ul`.

```
nav ul {
width: 809px;
height: 45px;
margin: 0 auto;
border-left: 1px solid #111;
border-right: 1px solid #444;
}
```

You can use Developer Tools(F12) to inspect elements.

Check this [image: screenshot].

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not work. The li element would still overflow.